# Bash - correct the formatting (sed?)

Tags: linux, bash

I've got an output of IFCONFIG which I've sanitized down to three main pieces:

1) IFNAME

2) IP Address

3) Netmask

This is currently done by the following string:

```
ifconfig -a | grep eth -A 1 | awk '{print $1,$2,$4}' | sed 's/Link HWaddr//g;s/inet addr\://g;s/Mask\://g;s/\-\-//g;/^$/ d' | grep -v 'UP\|^ '
```

The outputs looks like this:

```
eth0 
192.168.0.60 255.255.255.0
eth1 
1.1.1.1 255.255.255.0
eth2 
eth2:2 
10.2.2.1 255.255.255.0
eth2:3 
10.3.3.1 255.255.255.0
eth2:4 
10.4.4.1 255.255.255.0
eth2:5 
10.5.5.1 255.255.255.0
eth2:6 
10.6.6.1 255.255.255.0
eth2:7 
10.7.7.1 255.255.255.0
eth2:8 
10.8.8.1 255.255.255.0
eth2:9 
10.9.9.1 255.255.255.0
eth2:10 
10.10.10.1 255.255.255.0
eth2:11 
10.11.11.1 255.255.255.0
eth2:12 
10.12.12.1 255.255.255.0
eth2:13 
10.13.13.1 255.255.255.0
eth2:14 
10.14.14.1 255.255.255.0
eth3 
eth3.2 
10.30.30.1 255.255.255.0
eth3.7 
10.33.77.1 255.255.255.0
```

Now, I've got a few problems that I need correcting:

1) I need the formatting to be (IFNAME IP Address Netmask) which means I need to move the IP/Netmask up a line to it's associated IF

2) I'd like to remove the interfaces which currently have no configuration. In the example above you can see that eth2 and eth3 are lacking a configuration on the physical interface, and only have subinterfaces/vlans strung off of them.

Thank you again as always for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the following to your command:

```
$ ... | tr -d '\n' | sed 's/eth/\neth/g' | awk 'NF>1'
eth0 192.168.0.60 255.255.255.0
eth1 1.1.1.1 255.255.255.0
eth2:2 10.2.2.1 255.255.255.0
eth2:3 10.3.3.1 255.255.255.0
eth2:4 10.4.4.1 255.255.255.0
eth2:5 10.5.5.1 255.255.255.0
eth2:6 10.6.6.1 255.255.255.0
eth2:7 10.7.7.1 255.255.255.0
eth2:8 10.8.8.1 255.255.255.0
eth2:9 10.9.9.1 255.255.255.0
eth2:10 10.10.10.1 255.255.255.0
eth2:11 10.11.11.1 255.255.255.0
eth2:12 10.12.12.1 255.255.255.0
eth2:13 10.13.13.1 255.255.255.0
eth2:14 10.14.14.1 255.255.255.0
eth3.2 10.30.30.1 255.255.255.0
eth3.7 10.33.77.1 255.255.255.0
```

It first deletes all the new lines to pull everything up onto a single line and then uses `sed` to break it back into lines based on the `eth` field. Finally, it uses `awk` to print only those lines with more than 1 field.

(However, I'm sure your whole command can be simplified further. It looks like you have too many pipes!)

Comment: It looks like it does what I need it to though, thank you kindly :)

Comment: Had to look up what NF did, fancy :)

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, you can do all the manipulation in sed:

```
ifconfig -a | sed -ne '/^eth/{s/\n//;h;n;H;g;s/\(\S*\).*inet addr:\([0-9.]*\).*Mask:\([0-9.]*\).*/\1 \2 \3/;p;}'
```

Explanation:
For each line beginning with "eth", remove newline then put that line into hold space (h). Get the next line (n) and append that line to hold space (H). Overwrite current line with hold space (g). Perform a substitution on combined lines to pull out the useful bits, then print the results.